# How to use a function/task which is declared within a sub module in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

how can I use a function(function_a) declared within an entity (module_calling_fn_a), from another top entity(module_top) which has an instantiation of module_calling_fn_a.

This is possible in verilog, by the following
module_calling_fn_a. function_a ();

Is it possible in VHDL ?

Comment: The capacity to reference a subprogram declared in different entities architecture is explicitly prohibited see IEEE Std 1076-2008., 6.3 Selected names, paras 9,10. (VHDL doesn't call things modules and sub modules).

Answer (score 2):

The function will be local to `module_calling_fn_a` module, and cant't be used from another module.

Instead, to have the same function available in both modules, create a package and use that package in both modules.